# Patching decorator in setUp or setUpClass in TestCases does not work

Tags: python, testing, mocking, python-unittest

I am trying to patch some functions during either the `setUp` or `setUpClass` methods of a `unittest.TestCase` subclass.

Given a module `patch_me_not.py`

```
# patch_me_not.py
def patch_me(at):
    print('I am not patched at {}.'.format(at))

def patch_me_not(at):
    patch_me(at)
```

The following script produces more output that I would expect.

```
# main.py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
from patch_me_not import patch_me_not


@patch('patch_me_not.patch_me', lambda x: None)
class PatchMeNotTests(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print('I am the setUpClass.')
        patch_me_not('setUpClass')

    def setUp(self):
        print('I am the setUp.')
        patch_me_not('setUp')

    def test_print(self):
        print('I am the test')
        patch_me_not('test_print')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The test script output is

```
I am the setUpClass.
I am not patched at setUpClass.
I am the setUp.
I am not patched at setUp.
I am the test
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

OK
```

Where I would not expect the two "I am not patched at..." lines in the output if the patch worked in `setUp` and `setUpClass`.

How can I get the mock patch to be applied in these methods?

Comment: Can't you just remove the prints from your setup methods? I don't understand your issue. Do you want to supress all stdout output?

Comment: Its not about the function itself, this is just an example. In my real use case I am not patching `stdout.write`, but the same problem applies.

Comment: I updated my question to have a more complete example explaining the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need to do this:

```
class PatchMeNotTests(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    @patch('patch_me_not.patch_me', lambda x: None)
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print('I am the setUpClass.')
        patch_me_not('setUpClass')

    @patch('patch_me_not.patch_me', lambda x: None)
    def setUp(self):
        print('I am the setUp.')
        patch_me_not('setUp')

    def test_print(self):
        print('I am the test')
        patch_me_not('test_print')
```

Patching your test case did not work because when `patch` is applied to `TestCase` it patches *only* test methods or to be more specific: methods that start with a configurable prefix `patch.TEST_PREFIX` which default value is `"test"`. That's why your solution did not work.

Here is relevant quote from unittest docs

> Patch can be used as a TestCase class decorator. It works by
>   decorating each test method in the class. This reduces the boilerplate
>   code when your test methods share a common patchings set. `patch()`
>   finds tests by looking for method names that start with
>   `patch.TEST_PREFIX`. By default, this is `'test'`, which matches the way
>   unittest finds tests. You can specify an alternative prefix by setting
>   `patch.TEST_PREFIX`.

Comment: Great thanks, that does work indeed! Could you explain why the decorator at the class level does not work for these two methods?

Comment: @yellowcap I've updated my answer with an explanation