# How do you correctly mock a 3rd-party module in Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, module, mocking

I'm trying to write a simple unit test to test an instance method of one of my models in Django. However my class initialises an external connection on `__init__` which is not being patched even though I'm trying to target it.

**Folder Structure:**

```
- project/
  - app1/
    - tests/
      - tests_models.py
    - models.py
```

**models.py:**

```py
from 3rdPartyPlugin import Bot

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.bot = Bot(token)

    def generate_buttons(self):
        ...
```

**tests_models.py:**

```py
from django.test import TestCase
from unittest.mock import MagicMock, patch
from app1.models import MyClass

@patch('app1.models.3rdPartyPlugin.Bot')
class GenerateButtonsTestCase(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.tb = MyClass('', '', '')

    def test_generates_button_correctly(self):
        return True
```

I can't get past the `setUp` step because the initialisation of the class fails because it tries to reach out to that 3rdPartyPlugin module even though I patched it.

I've tried setting the patch to:

- @patch('app1.models.3rdPartyPlugin.Bot')
- @patch('app1.models.Bot')
- @patch('app1.models.TB.Bot')

But all of the above still leads to the Bot being called. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `Bot` is already imported and read in models.py before you patch it.
Try to import the whole module instead:

```
import 3rdPartyPlugin

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.bot = 3rdPartyPlugin.Bot(token)

    def generate_buttons(self):
```

Comment: Tried that and still getting a response from the 3rdPartyPlugin. Tried a few ways and still get this error:

`File "app1/models.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.bot = 3rdPartyPlugin.Bot(token)
  File ".pyenv/versions/3.7.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/3rdPartyPlugin/bot.py", line 133, in __init__
    self.token = self._validate_token(token)
  File ".pyenv/versions/3.7.6/lib/python3.7/site-packages/3rdPartyPlugin/bot.py", line 200, in _validate_token
    raise InvalidToken()
3rdPartyPlugin.error.InvalidToken: Invalid token`

Answer (score 0):

I eventually was able to solve this by moving the 3rdPartyPlugin code out of the initialiser and into an instance method on the class I was testing. This is how it looked in code:

**models.py:**

```py
from 3rdPartyPlugin import Bot

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, token):
        self.token = token
        self.bot = self.bot()

    def bot(self):
        Bot(self.token)
```

**tests_models.py:**

```py
from app1.models import MyClass

class GenerateButtonsTestCase(TestCase):
    @patch('app1.models.MyClass.bot')
    def setUp(self, _):
        self.tb = MyClass('', '', '')
```

And after making the above changes, the patch correctly works and patches my use of `Bot` from the 3rdPartyPlugin. It's a bit messy but it works for me.

Comment: The underlying reason is that when @patch is used as a class decorator, it patches all the methods that start with `test`. So if you have code that runs in setUp, it isn't patched which is why I was having endless issues. 

Credit to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52974104/1392697